# Why View All Data access is required to manage public dashboards?

Tags: dashboard

I was going through the documentation 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_reports_control_access.htm&language=en_US&type=0

As per the documentation it says that in order to manage public dashboard folders view all data access is required. I am not sure why is that? Is there any specific reason to give view all data to user who would manage dashboards?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's true and based on design.

If we want to **manage public dashboard** we need to see **ALL** data which other people has access. Dashboard data is getting populated from reports.

Here dashboard can be populated either based on Logged-in user or by specific users. Until we have all data access we cant validate that also.

Public dashboard manage means we need to see their data, otherwise we cant manage.

Hope it makes sense!

Comment: Thank you Santanu, this makes sense. I thought of same reason but is giving view all access doesn't feel so good. I will wait for some more responses, otherwise I will mark this as solution.

Comment: If the dashboard folder is Viewer or Editor access type then View All permission is not needed. Since it is specific requirement for Administration kind of activities, so View All justified

Comment: Are you happy with my answer?

Comment: Yes I am happy :)